# Alert with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new at JQuery and couldn't find answer in the Web.

So what is the usually used alternative in JQuery for standard JS ***alert*** function?

**UPDATE:** Maybe my question was little not clear. I know that Java Script's ***alert*** function is OK for JQuery. I ask about it alternative at JQuery. I do not like very poor abilities at *alert*. I would like to use something more powerful, e.g. with styles, buttons, titles, etc. So I would like to see the simple JQuery's alert analog invocation.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library .. So at the end of the day it is still javascript  .. So alert('Hello') will work with any library built on javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is a Javascript library. You don't need an alternative.

If you wish to use a javascript `alert()`, you can use it within your jQuery code as you would any Javascript code.

---

However, if you are looking for more freedom with the design, check out jQuery UI `.dialog()`:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I think my question is more about the second part of your answer about JQuery UI. What is the most used code for alerting with it?

Comment: @MichaelZ I would say that jQuery UI Dialog is the most used. Its built into jQuery UI so requires no additional plugin

Answer (score 3):

`You can use alert() in jquery, you used in javascript`. You can have custom plugins for showing message in jquery as well e.g [**jQuery Dialog**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative in `jQuery` itself, and as far as I know is not the jQuery goal to provide such alternatives. If you mean you want to use something mor efancy to display a message box, you can look at [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).